# Total no of terms in the expansion of $(x+z)^{50} +(x-z)^{50}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Please help me in solving the question and also tell me the technique so that I can easily solve it when similar question come in the form of Multiple choice questions MCQS.

Comment: By $xaz$ do you mean $x\cdot a\cdot z$ in which case $(xaz)^{50}=x^{50}a^{50}z^{50}$ and the expression above trivially has two terms... or perhaps you meant to have $+$ in place of the $a$?  or $-$ in place of the $i$?

Comment: sorry it was x plus z and x-z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individually, we expand the expressions.

$$(x+z)^{50} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}x^{50-k}z^k$$

$$(x-z)^{50}=(x+(-z))^{50}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}x^{50-k}(-z)^k$$

Each expansion comes from the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Now, we notice that when $k$ is even, the coefficient of $x^{50-k}z^k$ from the first is equal to the coefficient of $x^{50-k}z^k$ of the second (since a negative number raised to an even power is positive).  Further we notice that when $k$ is odd, the coefficients are of the same magnitude but are of opposite signs, and so when added will cancel out.

We have then

$$(x+z)^{50}+(x-z)^{50}=2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{25}\binom{50}{2k}x^{50-2k}z^{2k}$$

and in particular, this expression will have 26 (*nonzero*) terms.

Worded another way, the even indexed terms survive while the odd indexed terms disappear.  The $26$ even numbered terms between $0$ and $50$ (*inclusive*) survive, while the $24$ odd numbered terms between $0$ and $50$ disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Both $(x-z)^{50}$ and $(x+z)^{50}$ have $51$ terms after expanding them; however, those in which $z$ has an odd degree cancel out (do you understand why?), so we are left with $26$ terms.